# Does mysql connection error count ever flush or will the host eventually get blocked?

Tags: mysql, load-testing, mysql5.5

During performance testing of our application I found that under extreme loads one problem that can occur is the occasional mysql connection error (i.e. at this stage I don't believe it is fair to call it a bug). Eventually the application will get blocked by mysql. I can extend the `SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=10000;` (currently 10) but assuming 100% mysql uptime over a very very long time would this problem eventually reoccur?

This is the "blocked-host" feature of mysql:

> [Host 'host_name' is blocked because of many connection errors.
> Unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blocked-host.html)

Without proactive intervention will the connection error count ever flush or otherwise decline?

#### Update

I have found conflicting information, Percona recommend a very high limit ("around 1000000 is good") implying no. But elsewhere in the documentation states only *successive* errors are counted meaning yes, a single successful connection will flush the error count.

[8.11.5.2. DNS Lookup Optimization and the Host Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/host-cache.html)

> If too many of these occur **successively** from a given host without a
> successful connection, the server blocks further connections from that
> host. The max_connect_errors system variable determines the number of
> permitted errors before blocking occurs

Is anyone running mysql 5.6.5 where host_cache is exposed or know definitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are *successive* connection errors

Comment: maybe this is related https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69807

Answer (score 0):

> Does mysql connection error count ever flush?

No. The client host will be blocked until you execute a [`mysqladmin flush-hosts`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html) command or restart the MySQL server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The question is proactive and asking will the number of connection errors continue to increase *before* the host is blocked. I get the impression that if we expect very high traffic I will need to script a FLUSH every month